# How to open/ navigate multiple fragments in espresso testing in Android

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-navigation

I want to test complete one success flow in my Fragment Navigation using android espresso.

ex: Here there are two fragments and I want to **open first** one and verify something and then want to **open second** one. likewise want to test complete scenario.(A->B->C->D)

[image]

I tried using two fragment scenarios and populate but its not properly working.

```
fagmentScenario =launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme)
```